Seeking exercises about reducing the general equation of the quadric to the canonical form.
I need some equations for:

a hyperboloid with a canvas
a square cone (*)
elliptical paraboloid
elliptical cylinder (or hyperbolic cylinder) (*)
parabolic cylinder(*)
an example of a degenerate quadric (double plane/parallel planes/double right)(*)

The lines marked with (*) I need more. I would like them to have an average difficulty to solve, neither too easy nor too hard.
I want equations like the following:
$$2x^2 + 5y^2 + 11z^2 - 20xy + 4xz + 16yz - 24x - 6y - 6z - 180 = 0$$ (this is for hyperboloid with a canvas). The way I do it, is I calculate the characteristic polynomial and the eigenvalues, then $U(x_1)$, $U(x_2)$, $U(x_3)$, and then I make landmark changes $R\to R'\ldots R'\to R''$.
I need ONLY the respective equations in the form above, I don't need the solution, I will do that myself.

Welcome to Math.SE! ... You asked this question before. Re-posting to attract attention to it (or circumvent closure) is inappropriate. Rather, you should edit the original to improve its quality (eg, by adding the context you did here) in hopes of garnering re-open votes. (You can specifically request re-open consideration here.) Editing a question will "bump" it to the top of the Unanswered queue, so you get that benefit of a re-post without cluttering the site with duplicates. ... Good luck!

I understood, I deleted the other post and left this one where I explained... I hope it's okay and if there's anything else I need to do, please let me know, I'm new and I don't know how this place works

If you have access to a computer algebra system, then you could generate unlimited exercises like this yourself. Have the system start with the canonical form and apply random translations, rotations, and scalings (in random order, and perhaps repeatedly to really mix things up). You could, say, restrict the random parameters to integers, which might help keep the difficulty manageable.

Tell you what. We have no idea what your background might be. It seems that you are asking for problems to practice on yourself. Since you mention eigenvalues, it may be that you require easy (say, integer) eigenvalues. Suggest you pick some problem you have already done of modest difficulty, edit in that problem and your solution in your question. Meanwhile, it is possible that you are not demanding nice eigenvalues,  and this method will suffice:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Meanwhile, searching for hyperboloid with a canvas gave only https://www.pictorem.com/815180/Hyperboloid%20Vintage.html  I don't know what the word canvas means here. Also not the phrase "landmark changes."  Your suggested sequence with capital letter $R$  supports my idea of combined row/column operations, but who knows?

Echoing @WillJagy's comment, I've never heard "canvas" used in this context. Can you clarify? :)

You typed in one quadratic polynomial;
$$2x^2 + 5y^2 + 11z^2 - 20xy + 4xz + 16yz - 24x - 6y - 6z - 180.$$
Here is how it works out by multiple completing  the square. If the requirement is that the diagonal elements in $D$  are $0, 1, -1,$  this can be accomplished by a final step involving reciprocals of the square roots  of those (nonzero) absolute values.
The second version below, $Q^T DQ = H,$   says your polynomial is
$$  2 \left(x-5y+z-6 \right)^2 - 45 \left( y - \frac{2z}{5} + \frac{7}{5} \right)^2 + \frac{86}{5} \left( z - \frac{81}{86} \right)^2 - \frac{15399}{86 }  $$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
5 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 5 }{ 86 }  &  -  \frac{ 44 }{ 43 }  &  \frac{ 81 }{ 86 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 &  - 10 & 2 &  - 12 \\ 
 - 10 & 5 & 8 &  - 3 \\ 
2 & 8 & 12 &  - 3 \\ 
 - 12 &  - 3 &  - 3 &  - 180 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 5 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 86 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 44 }{ 43 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 81 }{ 86 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 45 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 86 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 15399 }{ 86 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 6 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 81 }{ 86 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 45 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 86 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 15399 }{ 86 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 5 & 1 &  - 6 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 81 }{ 86 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 &  - 10 & 2 &  - 12 \\ 
 - 10 & 5 & 8 &  - 3 \\ 
2 & 8 & 12 &  - 3 \\ 
 - 12 &  - 3 &  - 3 &  - 180 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
